# Kafka partition directories not deleted in data dir

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper  --delete --topic  and i see in kafka logs of that indicate that the partitions for that topic are marked for deletion. However, I am still seeing the directories for those partitions present in the data dir.

1. Is this something expected and I am have manually delete them?
2. The topics haven't been removed from the zookeeper also. I still see the topics in zookeeper. Is this also expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for topics not being deleted automatically.

In order to delete a topic `delete.topic.enable` should be set to `true`.

If it is set to true, it should ideally delete the directories from Zookeeper and kafka `data.dir` . But in case, if it doesn't, you should check the logs to make sure if there is any problem with kafka brokers or zookeeper due to some LEADER selection issue.

So in that case, you have to cleanup the dirs manually.